# In maven how to troubleshoot why wrong version of artifact was picked-up?

Tags: maven-3

I'm using maven to build project.
It uses some lib `A`, which in turn uses lib `B_v2`.

However when I do `mvn dependency:tree` I see that lib `B v1` is used. I don't want this to happen cause now when I run I have a combination of lib `A` + `B_v1` which were never  tested.

Obviously this is because some another artifact wins when lib versions are resolved and `B_v1` was used.

I want to know which artifact "won" and forces `B_v1` to be used (so I can fix this artifact to use `B_v2` too)

It must be one of the artifacts from `mvn dependency:tree` but there are a lot of them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the strategy used by Maven for dependency resolution, as described in [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) :

> - Dependency mediation - this determines what version of an artifact will be chosen when multiple versions are encountered as dependencies. Maven picks the "nearest definition". That is, it uses the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, the first declaration wins.
>
>   - "nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies. For example, if dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could explicitly add a dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0.

By default `mvn dependency:tree` does not list the dependencies that are omitted due to conflicting versions, so as long as `B` has the same `groupId` and `artifactId` in `v1` and `v2`, it should appear only once: the artifact that "won". (You can see all the omitted dependencies, marked as such, by using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`.)

Comment: I know I can force required version by defining it directly, but I was thinking to resolve this issue by finding artifact which trigger wrong version, fix it (check it works with a new version) and then use updated version of that artifact

Comment: In that case, the only way I see is using `dependency:tree` (or its equivalent in Eclipse/IntelliJ/Netbeans, that allows a cleaner view through filtering) and manually finding the "nearest first definition". That should do the trick, even though it is not the most practical thing to do. Maybe the addition of a feature similar to `yarn why` in the JS world in `maven-dependency-plugin` would be a nice thing to request or contribute to, so that such issue becomes less of a pain later on?

Comment: I don't have an answer to my exact question, but it looks like I just shouldn't care about it. May be I should declare all dependencies and versions i'm aware in the root project. `dependency:tree` prints same dependency many times in my case (it prints whole tree and so prints every usage of this dependency)

Comment: This is strange, according to the docs it shouldn't show more than one. Are you using the latest version of the plugin (3.1.1)? Or maybe there are some specificities in your project that I've never come across in mines that would explain it.

Comment: I would advise against declaring "all dependencies" (if you meant "even all the transitive ones") in your POM as it would make the updating of your direct dependencies pretty painful. It is better to keep it minimal, using only the dependencies your code directly uses (at `compile`, `test` or `runtime`), stick as much as possible with the "meta-dependencies" if you have some (the ones that only exist to bring a bunch of related dependencies, like the `spring-boot-starter-*` packages), and declare dependencies that should be transitive only to force a version or replace an excluded one.

Comment: Yes, i'm using `3.1.1`, I think each dependency printed once, I just have many artifacts, that's why same dependency appeared many times.